# Why is the asset I make in Sketch 3 slightly blurred?

Tags: ios, iphone, sketch-app

I'm making an app where I'm using sketch 3 to create image assets. First, I design something, click "make exportable" in the lower-right, chooses 0.5x and export it to somewhere on my Mac. Then, I drag the asset (*.png file) into Xcode 6 and for instance created an imageview with that asset as image - but if I look closely when running the app on my phone, the asset looks slightly blurred or not 100% focused, as if some of the color made it onto another pixel.. Does anyone have a clue on this? How can I make it sharper?

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 1):

**0.5x** means that if you have 1 pixel elements in your design, they will get blurred as no such thing as half a pixel exists. The concept behind 0.5x is that 1 pixel on the screen is filled on a retina display, which is half of the original @1x.

Comment: So I should rather export them as 1x and reduce the size in Xcode?

Comment: No that would have the same result. You should reconsider your concept. If you MUST have 1px retina assets then you should make the asset pixel-perfect for each resolution.

Comment: I just need them to appear the same in Xcode as in Sketch - what would be the optimal solution for that?

Comment: then you should make the asset pixel-perfect for each resolution.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by pixel-perfect?

Comment: In this specific case that you should make the assets separately in each resolution you are using them in. But "pixel-perfect" is a term you should search on this site or google as it it way too broad for one comment to explain.